# Xamarin Forms Scrollview and using Drag and Drop Gesture Recognizer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop, scrollview

I have a scrollview that has a bindable stacklayout inside it with a Item template that is using the drag and drop gesture recognizer. This works no problem but on android the drag gesture recognizer fires off immediately as soon as you start scrolling the screen. I'm curious if anyone has any ideas on how to handle keeping the gesture recognizer but also allow for the user to scroll the screen without dragging around an item in the list.

Comment: when I needed to have a drawing control inside a scrollview, I had to disable the scrollview when the drawing started and re-enable it when I was done.  I suspect that you will need to do something similar

Comment: Or try https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.HorizontalListView?

Comment: I don't think the list view will work because I need to have the whole page be scrollable. Thats why I am using a scrollview with a bindable stack layout inside it. But thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: I tested it on ios, and it  worksed, maybe you could post your problem in github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues